# Select all objects with max date for each ID with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this table:

```
Sn    Value      Data     
150   180.3    01/06/2020  
150   195.0    01/05/2020  
149   13.3     01/06/2020  
345   27.5     27/06/2013
....
```

I need to select all object with max data for each "Sn". That is I need such a result:

```
Sn    Value      Data     
150   180.3    01/06/2020  
149   13.3     01/06/2020  
345   27.5     27/06/2013
...
```

I have tried this query:

```
var obj = db.myTable.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(g => g.Sn)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)).FirstOrDefault();

using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("data.txt", true , System.Text.Encoding.Default)){
   foreach(var x in obj){
      sw.WriteLine($"{x.Sn} {x.Date} {x.Value}");
   }
}
```

But I get only objects with "Sn" = 150

I rely on SQL, this query would look something like this:

```
SELECT t.Sn, r.Data FROM (
SELECT Sn, MAX(data) as Date FROM MyTable GROUP BY Sn
) r
INNER JOIN myTable t
ON t.Sn = r.SN AND t.date = r.Data
```

but I'm not sure if it is correct and I don’t have enough knowledge to write it on linq

Comment: Change `.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)).FirstOrDefault();` to `.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());`

Comment: I will make an answer from that comment,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.FirstOrDefault` is applied in wrong place, outside `Select`. But you need to have the first element of **each group** thus instead of

```
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date))
.FirstOrDefault();
```

you need

```
.Select(
     g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
           .FirstOrDefault()
);
```

The only subtle difference is placing the `)` but I formatted the code for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call .ToList() to get all the records instead of .FirstOrDefault(), .FirstOrDefault() will take only the first or null (if doesn't exist)

```
var obj = db.myTable.AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(g => g.Sn)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)).ToList();
```